# SQL query - Join Two Sql Tables with different format

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 Tables in my datebase.
The first table called Table1 has a column called Fullnumber and contains 9 digits.
The second table called Table2 has a column called Shortnumber and contains  only the first 6 digits that appear in the Fullnumber column.
How can i join the two tables together?
There is no other matching column.

Thank you!

Comment: Column data type(s)?

Comment: The column data type is CHAR

Comment: Show table details with examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`:

```
from table1 join
     table2
     on table1.fullnumber like table2.shortnumber || '%'
```